# Catch incoming call state on iphone

Tags: iphone, state, phone-call

There is a way to catch incoming call on iPhone and send it to any server, I don't know,
like notification or something like that? I just need that state to be notified to any
server that I will create, to collect data about in/out calls from this iPhone and when it ends (like true or false - in call or ended call).
This application is installed and have notification center already.

Oh, and nothing works on background, just the springboard (I mean that it didn't exits any app when the call comes in/out).

Answer (score 1):

The only notification you get is that your application is being suspended (or put into the background).

You can't get any other notifications regarding phone call characteristics because Apple would consider that a privacy risk, and some governments are hyper-sensitive about this.

Comment: why not? I just want to send to my server notification that a call just came in, nothing else than that. I don't use any information about the carrier or the number itself, just sending "true" or "false".

Comment: It looks like you can check the state of a call. See @cocoanetics's answer. Also check out the Core Telephony sample code on Apple's site.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Core Telephony framework reference. Those are all the infos that we can get via public APIs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CoreTelephonyFrameworkReference/_index.html

Comment: I know that I can check the state of the call, but how can I send it to any server that I want without any application running at the background? I need to send it via something else. Any ideas?

Comment: You need to have an app running in a supported background mode.